# Is there a way to ovveride a method without extending the parent class?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I have a player class which extends a JLabel

```
public class Player extends JLabel
{
    public Player(int x,int y,int width,int height) throws IOException 
    {
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("Resources/Player.png")));
        this.setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

and I wanna override an Update method from a parent class to implement physics for the player but I have to extend the parent class which I cant do cause I already extended the JLabel, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you don't extend the class, it's not a parent class. but why on earth would 'Player' extend JLabel? that makes no sense at all. You should read up on when to use inheritance, and when to use composition. Personally: I see no reason why an actual Player would even be related to a JLabel.

Comment: The class which will have the Update Method is a JFrame class, and I just want my code to be neat which will be something like this ``` this.add(new Player(x,y,width,height);```

Comment: @Lyad be that as it may, it makes no sense to have Player inherit from any of them. to me, a Player is a class that contains the functionalities to actually play the audio. Then, you have a PlayerUI, which HAS a player (composition) attached, and HAS JLabels and such, it won't extend it

Comment: To answer the question, No! However you can use reflection to change a function behavior at run time, whether or not that helps you in any way, I'm not sure and don't recommend it.

Comment: btw: __never-ever__ do any manual sizing/locating of a component! Instead use a suitable layoutManager and implement the sizing constraints

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe you should add some context so we could see if another structure is more suited here and prevent your strange need.

Comment: You say you want to override the update method of the JFrame class.  Sure, you can.  Just create a class MyFrame that extends JFrame and override the method.  Then use MyFrame for your app instead of JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is probably no. You can/have to override methods that are declared in an implemented Interface or super class. So if the method you want to override is not declared in the JLabel class or a super class of JLabel, you will not be able to override (because you can't override what is not even written).

If you just want to use the icon functionality of JLabel, this would be a better approach than directly extending from it:

```
public class Player {

    private ImageIcon playerIcon = new ImageIcon("PATH TO ICON");
    private JLabel icon = new JLabel(playerIcon);
    
    public Player() {
        // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }
    
    public void setPlayerPosition(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        icon.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }
    
    public Point getPlayerPosition() {
        return icon.getLocation();
    }
}
```

I don't recommend using a NULL Layout and placing the components directly on the container, but this is a different topic

Because of the lack of information about what you exactly want to achieve, it is hard to give you advice how to achieve it. Specify your question, provide more code and information about the structure.

Comment: Thank you I think this will work, but I dont understand what you meant by choosing a null layout and placing the components directly on the container.